# using condition in loop on twig cycle

Tags: loops, symfony, twig

I want to stop the cycle if the loop is 3.
If my array has 5 records, I need to show only 3 records

```
{% for image in post.images %}
   {% if loop.index < '3' %}
      {{ loop.index}}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

so I want show only  3 loop

```
1  
2  
3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{% for image in post.images|slice(0, 3) %}
```

solved

Answer (score 0):

You can combine for and if statements in twig. Something like the below will work but I'm guessing it wouldn't actually be the loop index that you would ultimately be printing out?

```
{% for image in post.images if loop.index <= 3 %}
    {{ loop.index }}
{% endfor %}
```